# Java for Ubuntu12.04 LTS

Tags: java

I want to install Java from Java.com - In the site I see multiple options for Linux - which one to choose for Ubuntu 12.04 LTS? Why this is not available in Ubuntu SOftware centre?

Answer (score 1):

> Why this is not available in Ubuntu SOftware centre?

Oracle's Java is not free (as in freedom).  Its source code is not public and is released under a proprietary license.  Software available in the core Ubuntu repositories is all free software.  You can read more about that [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/our-philosophy).

I would suggest installing OpenJDK (which is free), it should suit your needs.  You can find it in the software centre, or type `sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre` (add `openjdk-7-jdk` if you need to do Java development) into the terminal.

If you do need Oracle Java, you can install it as vinaykrsharma suggested by following the instructions [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html).

Answer (score 0):

Java is available for Ubuntu in Software Center. Find `Open JDK` in software center and install.

Alternatively you can install Oracle Java from a PPA posted here:

http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to go for Oracle product?! May I suggest to try out also OpenJDK. I installed on my Ubuntu Server 13.04 through aptitude #apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk